# SQL Server Express 2014 - @@version 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a question reharding strange behavior of Sql Server. I had sql server 2008 edition which I uninstalled and installed SSMS Express 2014 instead. However I could not perform any advanced analytics on sample northwind db i.e. lead, lag, preceding etc.

When I asked the program `@@version`, the output was `2008sp4`.

How may it be that SSMS2014 has 2008 engine? How to fix it?

Comment: SSMS is a *UI application* that can connect to SQL Server. SQL Server, itself, is a windows service that has *no* UI of it's own. You've conflated the two. You may have changed management studio but you're not upgraded the server.

Answer (score 0):

There two applications such as SQL Server and SSMS.

SQL Server is a windows service which stores data. It does not have user interface.

SSMS is an UI application which connects to SQL Server to manipulate data by T-SQL language. It has user interface.

When you execute `@@version`, then you get a version of SQL Server.

If you want to know your SSMS version, then just click `Help` -> `About`